# Does Command work only for Button in Silverlight?

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I have a confusion that only button element shows option for command and most of the other elements do not support this option.
Is it valid only for Button?
And is only Click Event handled by Command?? Because most of the samples i have seen, On clicking button command gets fired.
In case i want command to be fired on other events, then what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are some limitations like above. A command cannot be bound with the controls that doesn't implement `ICommandSource` interface. But you can use **Dependency Property** to write custom commands.

You can see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363568/Command-binding-with-Events-a-way-from-simple-to-a) and [this](http://www.schwammysays.net/creating-custom-silverlight-4-controls-that-support-command-binding/) or googling for more examples.